# How to overwrite global event handler in nested Vue component, and later use the previous one?

Tags: events, vue.js, extending

I am working in Vue and also i use VueRouter, VueX and VueWebsocket. My App has component called App which holds all other components inside itself. Also I have websocket event which is set globally like this:

```
  this.$options.sockets.onmessage = (websocket) => { /* sth1 */ }
```

When it gets any data from websocket, sth1 is called. it works like charm. However deep inside App component is another component, let's call it InputComponent. It may be included in App or not becaue it is single page aplication and some parts do include InputComponent, and some do not. Inside InputComponent there is also:

```
  this.$options.sockets.onmessage = (websocket) => { /* sth2 */ }
```

And of course it overwrites function on message so sth1 will never be executed if  InputComponent is nested by App component. It is quite obvious. However if i remove (in next SPA page), and InputComponent disappears i still have my onmessage event overwritten which i would like to have in original version.

I could ofcourse make some kind of merging functionalities of sth1 and sth2 in App component or InputComponent but it is repeating myself.

Here comes the question - is there a way to return original version of onmessage event without reloading whole App Component? In other words: can i have temporary overwritten function and then come back to its functionalities? Something like extending an eent with new functionalities of sth2.

I hope you get the idea!
K.

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do that would be to use `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`. So in the input component

```
created() {
    this.$options.sockets.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
},
destroyed() {
    this.$options.sockets.removeEventListener('message', handleMessage);
}
```

Note that this approach doesn't prevent the original handler from also receiving the events. Without knowing more about the app architecture, it's hard to suggest the best way to avoid this behavior, but perhaps you can set a `messageHandled` flag on the event in the component's handler; then check that flag in the parent.

Comment: That would work great if both original and component event would fire, but unfortunatelly i get [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: this.$options.sockets.addEventListener is not a function". After reading some docs i found out that not every element may have addEventListener:(

Comment: Then `this.$options.sockets` must not be a WebSocket.